# Please help me identify my Giant Sedona

Tags: identify-this-bike, giant

[image]

Could someone help me identify this thing? Thanks to anyone that is willing to help

Comment: It's a... Giant Sedona/  Seriously, what do you want to know about it?  Any idea one what parts have been updated?  The straight downtube suggests 2005 or earlier, while the quick release on the front wheel gong by my 30secs in the Giant archive suggests they aren't standard

Comment: What are you trying to find out about it?   Looks like a garage princess - the tyres are dry rotted on the side walls, but have perfect-looking tread.  I bet the bike's not done 100 miles in its entire life so the rim's brake tracks will be flat.   It needs new tyres and brake pads to be ridden safely, and any lubricants will likely be dried up and tacky so a degrease and re-lube would be wise.